# OpenGL ES 2 without GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I want to make an app that uses OpenGL ES 2.0.
Can I do this without using GLKit, since I want to deploy it to iOS 4.3? I can't find any reference on this.
Is it even possible to use shaders etc without GLKit?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can develop in OpenGL ES 2.0 with shader support without using GLKit. GLKit is only there to make simple tasks easier but you don't have to use it at all. For starters have a look at the guide provided by Apple that outlines different approaches:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793

Apple also provides sample code, for example this one has a renderer for ES 2.0 and the build requirements are iOS SDK 4.0 or higher:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010104

Comment: Yeah, we were doing OpenGL ES 2.0 development on iOS long before GLKit was around. It has some nice helper functions and classes, but everything it does can be done without GLKit. As an example, my entire framework here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage uses OpenGL ES 2.0, targets iOS 4.0, and doesn't use GLKit. I personally haven't used GLKit yet in any of my own OpenGL ES projects.