# Problems creating (from scratch) iOS 7.0 OpenGL ES 2.0 App WITHOUT using GLKIT

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

This is not a duplicate of [OpenGL ES 2 without GLKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969809/opengl-es-2-without-glkit)

I've been programming OpenGL on iOS for 4 years and ES2 for almost 2.  But with the addition of GLKit and Storyboards, and with the latest Xcode, the project templates are different.  And there is no longer an OpenGL template that creates an EAGLView Class.  I don't want to use GLKit.  I prefer to always do things programmatically. I try to avoid nibs and I've never used storyboards before.  But in this case below I'm leaving them as is from the template.

My steps:

I start with a new project and pick Single View Application.  I run it and it runs fine with a white screen.

Next I go to Build Phases and add QuartzCore, OpenGLES.

Then I do New File and add an Objective-C class, make it a subclass of UIView and call it EAGLView.  In the .h I import  and the EAGLContext *context

In the .m in the initWithFrame I add this initialization code...

```
    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

    eaglLayer.opaque = TRUE;


    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                    kEAGLColorFormatRGB565, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,

                                    nil];

    // Creates the EAGLContext and set it as the current one.
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    if (!_context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context])
    {
        NSLog(@"_context no workie!");
        return nil;
    }
```

In my ViewController.h I add `@class EAGLView;` and a property `EAGLView *glView;`

In the ViewController.m in the viewDidLoad I add:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
int width=rect.size.width;
int height=rect.size.height;


glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    glView.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}
glView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
self.view = glView;
```

and I run it.  I get this error message:

`-[CALayer setDrawableProperties:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e441c0`

How does my CAEAGLLayer eaglLayer not have a selector of .drawableProperties?  Did I miss a step somewhere?

*** UPDATE ***

I found this solution:

In the EAGLView.m I added the following:

```
+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

And now it runs without crashing.  Can anyone tell me why I need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always needed to override this method. It seems the default layer class is the `CALayer` which has no `setDrawableProperties:` method. You can see the `CAEAGLLayer` is a subclass of the `CALayer`.

Somewhere along the pipeline something like this is called

```
[[[self class] layerClass] performSelector:@selector(setDrawableProperties:) withObject:properties];
```

which generates the exception without you overriding the `layerClass` method.

Comment: I expect that you're right. But any idea why we didn't have to do it with the older templates. Seems like it's only required now with storyboards.  I have another project that uses nibs instead of storyboards and it runs fine without the override.

Comment: I never use storyboards or GLKit, the GLKView is probably already implementing this method. As for the older versions I am pretty sure this method was always there in the template, I know I had the same issue quite a few years ago when I didn't start with the apple template but with a simple UIView. There were no storyboards back then and I think this method was actually in the apple documentation.

Comment: You're right.  I just checked and it's been in all my older code.  Not sure how I missed it.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL can only be use on [CAEAGLayer class], and

```
 + (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

mean layer of this view is a CAEAGLayer.